# UpdateThread interrupted. Don't worry - this EngineDestroyedException is most likely expected

Tags: andengine

I've recently started to using Andengine.I wrote this code with the help of tutorial videos.I wanted set background color and add a ball(top.png) to scene.
When I run program coming a black screen and shortly after emulator throwing error
I ran into the following error:

```
UpdateThread interrupted. Don't worry - this EngineDestroyedException is most likely expected!
org.andengine.engine.Engine$EngineDestroyedException
at org.andengine.engine.Engine.throwOnDestroyed(Engine.java:574)
at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onTickUpdate(Engine.java:560)
at org.andengine.engine.Engine$UpdateThread.run(Engine.java:820)

and my code:

   package com.example.oyundeneme2;

   import org.andengine.engine.camera.Camera;
   import org.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions;
   import org.andengine.engine.options.ScreenOrientation;
   import org.andengine.engine.options.resolutionpolicy.RatioResolutionPolicy;
   import org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
   import org.andengine.entity.scene.background.Background;
   import org.andengine.entity.util.FPSLogger;
   import org.andengine.opengl.texture.TextureOptions;
   import org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlas;
   import org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory;
   import org.andengine.opengl.texture.region.TextureRegion;
   import org.andengine.opengl.texture.region.TiledTextureRegion;
   import org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity;

   import android.view.Display;

   public class OyunEkrani1 extends BaseGameActivity{


    private static final int CAMERA_WIDTH=800;
    private static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT=480;

    private Camera myCamera;

    private BitmapTextureAtlas myBackgroundTextureAtlas;
    private TextureRegion myBackgroundTextureRegion;

    //private Engine myEngine;
    private Scene myScene;

    private TiledTextureRegion myCircleFaceTextureRegion;

    @Override
    public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {

    this.myCamera=new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);

    final Display myDisplay=getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();



    EngineOptions FixedStepEngine=new EngineOptions(true,
    ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, 
    new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), myCamera);


        return FixedStepEngine;
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreateResources(
            OnCreateResourcesCallback pOnCreateResourcesCallback)
            throws Exception {


    BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");
    this.myBackgroundTextureAtlas=
    new BitmapTextureAtlas(null,1024,512,TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
    this.myCircleFaceTextureRegion =BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createTiledFrom
    Asset(this.myBackgroundTextureAtlas, this, "top.png", 60, 60, 0, 0); // 64x32

    this.mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(this.myBackgroundTextureAtlas);


    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateScene(OnCreateSceneCallback pOnCreateSceneCallback)
            throws Exception {
        mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());

        myScene = new Scene();
        myScene.setBackground(new Background(0.59804f, 0.5274f, 0.5784f));
    }

    @Override
    public void onPopulateScene(Scene pScene,
            OnPopulateSceneCallback pOnPopulateSceneCallback) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

return your scene in "onCreateScene".Try this

Comment: whats wrong with this? You have to return your scene through callback pOnCreateSceneCallback.onCreateSceneFinished(scene);and also to your onLoadResourcers() i.e. pOnCreateResourcesCallback.onCreateResourcesFinished();

Comment: If you are extending BaseGameActivity then you have to  implement callback to all your overridden methods